# Command works when run with -it and bash, but not with CMD inside Docker

Tags: node.js, docker, meteor

I want to run a very simple dev Docker on WSL2 Win 10 with the command npm start, but it throws a

> sh: 1: meteor: not found

error when run via `docker run -p 3000:3000 meteordev`

BUT, when I run it with `docker run -it -p 3000:3000 meteordev bash` and run `npm start` on the container command line it runs perfectly.

I guess this has to do with how the env is configured for both, but I can't get it to work, any ideas?

Here ist the full Docker image. If there is another short one, I am happy to drop mine:

```
# Mini-Docker
FROM node:14

RUN adduser --disabled-password --shell /bin/bash newuser
RUN chown -R newuser /usr/local/lib/node_modules
RUN chown -R newuser /usr/local/bin
USER newuser

COPY --chown=newuser:newuser ./app /home/newuser/app
RUN chmod -R 700 /home/newuser/app/.meteor/local

WORKDIR /home/newuser/app
RUN npm install -g meteor@latest

EXPOSE 3000
CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

Comment: The `1` in the error message might indicate that something is trying to read from `stdin`. Does it work if you do `docker run -it -p 3000:3000 meteordev`?

Comment: Do you need to `RUN npm ci` (or `npm install`) to install everything listed in your `package.json` file?  You shouldn't need to install packages by name in your Dockerfile.

Comment: (I might remove all of the `chown` and `chmod` parts of this and let the root user own the application files, but switch to `USER newuser` at the very end of the file.  This would prevent a bug from accidentally overwriting the application code, and significantly simplify the Dockerfile.)

Comment: Thanks @HansKilian, I tried to run it with -it (same problem).

Comment: Thanks @DavidMaze, Meteor's new way of installation is via npm, therefore we need the chowns or we get some errors.  I am just unsure why it works when I run the image via bash. Is there a way to give the CMD paths etc. from bash other than /bin/bash -c or SHELL ...?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, if you run `npm` directly, it will not run in a shell and hence your `PATH` will not be set.

This works:

```
ENV PATH="$PATH:/home/newuser/.meteor"
CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

I suppose, if you ran the `npm install -g meteor@latest` *before* switching to `newuser`, then it might work as well, because then meteor will be installed globally on the system, rather then globally for the new user only. But I haven't tested that.

Comment: Thanks, works like a charm, I knew I had to add the path somewhere. I did install meteor without a user before, but somehow I had problems with the rights. Will have to cleanup that part now :-)

Comment: Fun fact, `CMD ["bash", "-c", "npm", "start"]` doesn't work, maybe WSL, you'll get `Usage: npm <command>`, so it doesn't recognize the start part ... strange.

Comment: ah yes, it may need to be `CMD ["bash", "-c", "npm start"]`

Comment: But it doesn't work as standalone `CMD ["bash", "-c", "npm start"]` (still same error as above), if you want it to run, you need the `ENV PATH="$PATH:/home/newuser/.meteor"` before the CMD

Comment: ok thanks. I've updated the answer to correct that.